# login_required decorator in Django: open modal instead of redirecting to another page

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a django app which has certain sections which are reserved for registered users. I have the views annotated with login_required decorator which redirects the user to a login page.

However, I would like to keep the user on the same page and open up a modal dialog prompting user to sign in(like on the website: http://www.fashiolista.com/). 
To achieve this, I thought I could setup a middleware(instead of using login_required) and return a response like below:

```
   return HttpResponse("<script>"
       "showLogin()"
       "</script>")
```

When I try to do this, I realised that this renders a page with only the script tag, which obviously doesnt work.

I am using Bootstrap for showing modal dialogs.

Middleware link: http://onecreativeblog.com/post/59051248/django-login-required-middleware

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Instead it should be an ajax call to happen in real time, and add the modal to your base.html.

Django View:

```
def login_required_ajax_view(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return JsonResponse(data={'logged_in', True})
        return JsonResponse(data={'logged_in', False})
    return HttpResponse("not ajax")  # Add something if the call isn't ajax
```

Then in your javascript

```
// Javascript / Jquery
function login_required() {
    $.ajax({
       url: 'url goes here',
       data: data
       success: success  //on success call a function checking logged_in is 
                                   //true or false then open modal to log in.
    })
}
```

If it returns true allow them to click the button and move on to the next page.

On a side note:

If you're routing all of your urls through django and not javascript, then the modal will not appear if they go directly to a url in the browser. If this is a one page app then there is alot more to be done to get any of this to work. You need javascript libraries, a router, etc,

Comment: I am not sure I understand the flow. How does the method login_required_ajax_view get called? Are you suggesting that I put a call to login_required (javascript/jquery method) on each anchor element in my html? This would call login_required_ajax_view on the backend, if logged_in then redirect to page else open login/sign up modal.

Comment: Well first off, is this a 1 page app? If it is then this is not the correct way to go about it, if anything I'd recommend websockets. Anyways the flow works this way, you set the links to run this function that require login via jquery, then on success run a function verifying the login_required key as part of data returned, if False open modal

Comment: After that to do a real ajax login you need a bit more coding such as setting the cookie to request but even then the django templating only renders on page reload, it really depends on the structure of your app, if you're more clear on what you want it makes it easier to give a definite answer

Comment: I understand the flow now. This is not a one page app. One issue I see with this approach is that I will have to keep track of both login url and login redirect url in the front end. I guess I could determine the urls when I render the template and modify the login_required function to login_required(login_success_url, login_failed_url). Thanks for your help!

Comment: There's something we say at my company: Bloop bloop

Answer (score 0):

Just accomplish this in your template

```
<html>
    ...
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}

    <div class="reserved-section">...</div>

    {% else %}

    <script> modal(); </script>

    {% endif %}
```

Alternatively, render different templates via your view

```
def some_page(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, "template_a.html")
    else:
        return render(request, "template_b.html")
```

**Update**

Use javascript logic in your template if you need to make an action

```
<script>
    function actionOnClick() {
        var logged_in = {% if user.is_authenticated %}true{% else %}false{% end %};
        if(logged_in){
            ..
        }
        ..
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think this would work. I need to open up a modal when a user clicks on a reserved link, this can only be determined when a user clicks on a link. The above seems to determine this when it renders the template

Comment: Similar to Mikeec3's suggestion, there are a  couple of issues with this approach, for instance, I will have to keep track of restricted links in the frontend, I will have to specify a login_redirect link(in case of failed login) with each link etc.